# Make not producing new executable if one is already present

Tags: c, makefile

I have the following makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-std=c89

driver: driver
    $(CC) -o driver driver.c

clean:
    rm -f driver
```

Running make produces the driver executable. Now, if I modify the driver.c file and run
make again it does compile the new .c file but doesn't replace the one already there
Is that an expected behavior, or am I missing something here?

Comment: That's why you run ``make clean; make``.

Comment: Do not use `-std=c89` except when working with very old software that requires it. For new software today, use `-std=c18` unless there is good reason not to.

Comment: Your title says `make` is “not producing a new executable if one is already present“ but your question says it does “replace the one already there”. You should edit the title or the body of the question to clarify.

Comment: @EricPostpischil edited it. Inside driver.c  I include two custom header files. Should that reflect in the makefile? Although its building fine

Comment: Make will show you a warning with this makefile, saying `make: Circular driver <- driver dependency dropped.`  You should pay attention to that as it pointed you in the right direction.  Also, you should probably include information like that in the question you asked: cut and paste the command you invoked and the output you received.

Comment: Re “Should that reflect in the makefile?”: If you want the program to be rebuilt if the header files have changed, they should be listed in the dependency.

Answer (score 4):

`driver: driver` says `driver` depends on itself. That is not correct. You want `driver: driver.c` to say `driver` depends on `driver.c`.

(And that is fine for a very simple project with one executable that depends on one source files. In more complex projects, you will want executables to depend on object files and possibly other types of files and will want object files to depend on source files and possibly headers and possibly other files.)